# android adb usage, identify offline devices

Tags: android

On page 2 of this document http://gauss.ececs.uc.edu/Courses/c6053/lectures/PDF/environ.pdf

I am trying to run the following commands (with the given responses)

```
kn@MrCo:~$ adb devices emulator-554 offline 
Usage: adb devices [-l]
kn@MrCo:~$ adb devices emulator-5554 device 
Usage: adb devices [-l]
```

How might I use these commands properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's suggesting you just type `adb devices`, and the "emulator..." lines shown in the instructions are the responses `adb devices` produces.  they just chose poorly in colouring them in the same font colour.

See here: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html

> Here's an example showing the devices command and its output:
>
> ```
> adb devices
> List of devices attached
> emulator-5554  device
> emulator-5556  device
> emulator-5558  device
> ```

Comment: Ooooooohhhhh, Well that makes a lot more sense now.